# What the best way for saving webservice response in DB?

Tags: c#, .net

I am calling a webservice which returns me a name value pair xmlarraylist , along with few other parameters which can be directly mapped against table columns. I am concerned about the the response parameter which is xmlarraylist whose length is dynamic.

i want to save such webservice response in DB. Which approach should one be using , considering in mind that it should be a scalable solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing away the XML directly into the db (xml field) would be the most obvious way. You are limited by the capacity specifications of your chosen db. In case of MSSQL, *stored representation of xml data type instances cannot exceed 2 GB*, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think XML is the most scalable.